How to limit number of files in BigQuery to GCS upload
I am uploading csv files to GCS via EXPORT statement in BigQuery. I want to reduce the number of files being uploaded. The documentation states that datasets that exceeds 1GB will be splitted into multiple files but doesn’t explain how to manipulate with the number of files.
I did some workaround by using SELECT DISTINCT so it doesn’t create files based on table partition but based on worker threads. So I ended up with 200 files but I want to reduce it even more - up to 100 files.

Take a look in Limit the exported file size

My gut is saying that we won't have specific control over the size and number of files.  My thinking is that since BigQuery is massively parallel, what it is doing is distributing the export across some large number of internal workers where each worker is responsible for writing its own portion of the data.  To collapse the output, we would have to aggregate the data together which would be less efficient.
